# Implementing introspection in c++ (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering if somebody could clarify the following for me. I'm about to sit a test in relation to Qt and the sample questions are rather ambiguous. One of the questions are as follows:

**Qt implements introspection in c++ by:**

a. Automatically defining every class as QObject.

b. Defining meta objects that can call itself within a QObject class.

c. Defining a meta object associated to every QObject.

I know that to have introspection you must have QObject inherited (this also implements signals and slots), and using the Q_OBJECT macro makes it so that it can be replaced by the MOC. I have a feeling it could be anyone of these answers but I'd like somebody to clarify. I think it's A but I could be wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have a Qt dev environment then I suggest looking at the generated moc file and when the Q_OBJECT macro adds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt implements introspection through storing information about every `QObject` derived *class* (and one that has the `Q_OBJECT` macro) in a `QMetaObject` (read [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/metaobjects.html#meta-object-system)).  The `QMetaObject` is built by the `moc` pre-processor.

I wouldn't consider any of your 3 options correct:

1. **a** is blatantly wrong.
2. **b** does not make sense as a sentence.
3. **c** is correct if you add *subclass* at the end.

There's a little more information [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/moc.html#moc) regarding the `moc`.

Comment: Thank you very much and I totally agree with what you said in regards to the subclass being added to the end--it makes much more sense having it there.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is C.

- A: Qt does not make every class inherit from QObject (you have to do it explicitely);
- B: I'm not sure what does this mean, but objects can't call themselves, as C++ has not introspection itself, and that is why...
- C: is true. It is handled by Q_OBJECT macro which marks a class for MOC (Qt's Meta Object Compiler) in order to generate associated QMetaObject regular-C++ code for that marked class. Each QObject stores pointer to its own QMetaObject instance and a second pointer to static QMetaObject instance containing informations about its class.

Comment: Your last point is incorrect, from the `QMetaObject` docs: "A single QMetaObject instance is created for each QObject subclass that is used in an application, and this instance stores all the meta-information for the QObject subclass. This object is available as QObject::metaObject()."  There is only `QMetaObject` instance per class.

Comment: It is correct. I mentioned "second pointer", not "second instance" - because in most cases it is reference to the same instance, but NOT in every case - execute sample code:
http://pastebin.com/kefegRE7

Comment: Surely that example isn't valid as calling a static member isn't polymorphic, so your first line is returning what you expect, but the second is returning the `QMetaObject` for a `QQuickItem`.  I can't find any example of what you're saying in Qt's source code.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency (I guess), Qt does *not* derive each type from a common base, like Java or .NET do.

QObject exposes QMetaObject, that indeed allows a great deal of reflective programming, but the most fundamental meta programming tool is instead [QMetaType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html).

Indeed some frequently used classes, like QPen, or QSize, that are 'root' objects, i.e. don't derive from anything at all, or your own classes, can be made available to metaprogramming via a macro, Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

The purpose is to make available to [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html) *construction and copy* of generic objects. Then, since property exchange or method invoking are defined (at system level),  using QVariant, such objects can be put to good use.

It's a 'mixed', efficient architecture, that sometime requires hardcoding the interface to literals. Generic interfaces are availabe, but only on *binary* data. Again, for efficiency.