# Edit struct with qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a struct that represent my binary data in one program. And I would like to create a GUI to easy edit it with validate. Example struct here, my has 1k bytes size.

```
struct Conf {
    uint8_t  vers;
    uint16_t mode;
    const char * msg[26];
    unit16_t size;
    uint64_t uid;
    uint16_t crc;
}
```

I would like to auto generate GUI for it with labels "vers", "mode", "size"... and I would also want easy add versification function (for example check crc) and `generate_bin`. It is possible with qt? What is more that struct is in develop mode so many fields can be changed for example i will change type of `mode` to `enum: uint16_t` because there are just a few valid numbers.

It would be nice to make it work on mobile (but it's not necessary).

Comment: how do you get 1k byte size? I expect thirty something bytes for this `struct`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing introspection in c++ (Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931082/implementing-introspection-in-c-qt)

Comment: In terms of C++ alone, no, but look up the various current proposals for adding introspection to the language.

Comment: ... do you mean the one you show here is just an example, but the real one has 1kb ?

Comment: Aside from all that, you could probably quite quickly hack together e.g. an `awk` script to generate widget code for the fields. But that's only worth doing if the fields will change often enough that writing that script would be quicker than simply manually writing the GUI code you need right now.

Comment: you can describe structure you want in txt file, and then genrate code for struct and for gui on base of txt file context, so you would not need to check correspondence between fields in gui/struct.